# How to select the Date Picker In Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**. I want to select values in `date range` from the drop down.. I want to know how can I select the values as `Date, Month and year` in the date picker drop down.

Here is the HTML tag:

```
<dd id="date-element">
<input id="fromDate" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" style="width:57px; padding:3px 1px; font-size:11px;" readonly="readonly" name="fromDate" value="01 Jan 2013">

<input id="toDate" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" style="width:57px; padding:3px 1px; font-size:11px;" readonly="readonly" name="toDate" value="31 Dec 2013">
```

[image]

The below sample code i tried:

```
Log.info("Clicking on From daterange dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor8 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor8.executeScript("document.getElementById('fromDate').style.display='block';");
Select select8 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fromDate")));
select8.selectByVisibleText("10 Jan 2013");
Thread.sleep(3000);

Log.info("Clicking on To daterange dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor10 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor10.executeScript("document.getElementById('toDate').style.display='block';");
Select select10 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("toDate")));
select10.selectByVisibleText("31 Dec 2013");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Dates are not `Select` elements. They are tables indeed

Comment: Check this example - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-custom-controls-datepicker/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

DatePicker are not `Select` element. What your doing in your code is wrong.

Datepicker are in fact table with set of rows and columns.To select a date you just have to navigate to the cell where our desired date is present.

So your code should be like this:

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(your locator);
List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

for (WebElement cell: columns){
   //Select 13th Date 
   if (cell.getText().equals("13")){
      cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();
      break;
 }
```

Comment: @ Ant's you are telling only to click the date but i don't entire picker for month and year also.. could you give me some more examples.

Comment: Isnt it required to cast as following @Ant's?
List<WebElement> columns = (List<WebElement>) dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

Comment: @hirosht: Why to cast ?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this, see if it works for you.

Rather than choosing date from date picker, you can enable the date box using javascript & enter the required date, this would avoid excessive time required to traverse through all date elements till you reach one you require to select.

Code for
**from date**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('fromDate').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); // Enables the from date box

WebElement fromDateBox= driver.findElement(By.id("fromDate"));
fromDateBox.clear();
fromDateBox.sendKeys("8-Dec-2014"); //Enter date in required format
```

Code for
**to date**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('toDate').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); // Enables the from date box

WebElement toDateBox= driver.findElement(By.id("toDate"));
toDateBox.clear();
toDateBox.sendKeys("15-Dec-2014"); //Enter date in required format
```

Comment: This works perfectly though it is not ethical for automation, as the users's interaction behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly use following javascript

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('fromDate').setAttribute('value','10 Jan 2013')")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be done in a much simpler way:

1. Find the locator for the Month (use Firebug/Firepath)
2. This is probably a Select element, use Selenium to select Month
3. Do the same for Year
4. Click by linkText "31" or whatever date you want to click

So code would look something like this:

```
WebElement month = driver.findElement(month combo locator);
Select monthCombo = new Select(month);
monthCombo.selectByVisibleText("March");

WebElement year = driver.findElement(year combo locator);
Select yearCombo = new Select(year);
yearCombo.selectByVisibleText("2015");

driver.click(By.linkText("31"));
```

This won't work if the date picker dropdowns are not Select, but most of the ones I've seen are individual elements (select, links, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

try to SendKeys instead of picking the date

```
driver.FindElement(yourBy).SendKeys(yourDateTime.ToString("ddd, dd.MM.yyyy",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

If it does not work, try to send native 'tab'

```
element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
```

Comment: You know what? This is what i end up doing, somehow when I use Selenium to test with Chromedriver, my electron app with the date picker didn't have all the date tags in there, even though it displays, so I end up having to send inputs using sendKeys anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String datePicker(String object,String data){
    APP_LOGS.debug("selecting date");
    try{

        WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object)));

        List<WebElement> rows = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
        List<WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

        for (WebElement cell: columns){
            if (cell.getText().equals(data)){
                cell.findElement(By.linkText(data)).click();
                break; 
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" -- Not able to select the date"+e.getMessage();
    }
    return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not inject javascript. That is a bad practice.

I would model the DatePicker as an element like textbox / select as shown below.

For the detailed answer - check here- http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-custom-controls-datepicker/

```
public class DatePicker {

    private static final String dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";

    @FindBy(css = "a.ui-datepicker-prev")
    private WebElement prev;

    @FindBy(css = "a.ui-datepicker-next")
    private WebElement next;

    @FindBy(css = "div.ui-datepicker-title")
    private WebElement curDate;

    @FindBy(css = "a.ui-state-default")
    private List < WebElement > dates;

    public void setDate(String date) {

        long diff = this.getDateDifferenceInMonths(date);
        int day = this.getDay(date);

        WebElement arrow = diff >= 0 ? next : prev;
        diff = Math.abs(diff);

        //click the arrows
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
            arrow.click();

        //select the date
        dates.stream()
            .filter(ele - > Integer.parseInt(ele.getText()) == day)
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(ele - > ele.click());

    }

    private int getDay(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
        LocalDate dpToDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
        return dpToDate.getDayOfMonth();
    }

    private long getDateDifferenceInMonths(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
        LocalDate dpCurDate = LocalDate.parse("01 " + this.getCurrentMonthFromDatePicker(), dtf);
        LocalDate dpToDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
        return YearMonth.from(dpCurDate).until(dpToDate, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
    }

    private String getCurrentMonthFromDatePicker() {
        return this.curDate.getText();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 you can use this simple method for picking a random date from the date picker

```
List<WebElement> datePickerDays = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
datePickerDays.stream().filter(e->e.getText().equals(whichDateYouWantToClick)).findFirst().get().click();
```