# Select from a DatePicker in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone help me with the Selenium webdriver (in Python) code to automatically select a date in the input date in the above link.

https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm

It is just one line of code but I've wasted hours behind it. someone please kindly help. I've tried the .send_keys() function and have searched for hours about the datepicker issue. Kindly help.

Comment: Go through this link might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422548/how-to-select-the-date-picker-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: See my answer below. Why do you think that it needed just one line of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You havn't mentioned exactly where you are stuck while automatically sending a date in the `<input>` tag. How ever the `<input>` tag is having *type* as **text** and the following code block works perfect :

- Code Block :

  ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
   driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm")
   print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='textboxdata hasDatepicker' and @id='date']").send_keys("10-04-2018")
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
   Page Title is : NSE - National Stock Exchange of India Ltd.
  ```
- Snapshot :

[image: NSE]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Calendar date picker Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136519/calendar-date-picker-selenium-python/65142989#65142989)

Comment: I agree that this works fine but are you testing the datepicker in this way?

Comment: @Frank OP's question heading reads as _Select a date in a website_ and in the question body OP mentioned about using `send_keys()` but not `@Test` _Datepicker_ functionality. Thanks

Comment: but he "searched for hours about the datepicker" so that's why my answer focusses on the datepicker.

Comment: @Frank While handling _Datepicker_ functionality the procedure you followed is the best way. But OP explicitly mentioned about `send_keys()` hence my Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. But there seems to be a problem. When I run this code (opening chrome), it did print the title but then it gave me this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'` is a common error due to mismatch in binary versions and you can solve it following the discussion [unknown error: call function result missing 'value' for 
@MuditGupta Selenium Send Keys even after chromedriver upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even/49452443#49452443)

Comment: The calendar popup is not dismissed after send keys. How can I make the calendar dismissed?

Answer (score 4):

For instance clicking on the 5 of march 2017:

```
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm")

datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("date")
datepicker.click()

selectMonth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="ui-datepicker-month"]')
for option in selectMonth.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Mar':
        option.click() 
        break

selectYear = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="ui-datepicker-year"]')
for option in selectYear.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == '2017':
        option.click() 
        break 

days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-state-default"]')
days[4].click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Jquery` is included:

`driver.execute_script('$("#date_element").val("1977-01-22")')`

else:

`driver.execute_script('document.getElementById('date_element').value ="1977-01-22"')`