# How to inject the value for a datepicker in selenium using JavaScript?

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker, selenium-chromedriver

I'm setting up a project to download images from our client using selenium using **java** and **ChromeDriver**.

I feel that selecting the `datepicker` image, then selecting the year/month/day individually feels a bit redundant.

Is there a way for me to inject the value directly without having to set the driver up to go through that entire process of looking for the correct dates?

I've tried setting up the [click process](https://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html), it works perfectly, but it feels as if it can be accomplished in 1/10 of the time.

Comment: I manged to solve this by doing the following:

public void setDateFrom(String date) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        js.executeScript("var drpfromdatePeriod = $('#drpfromdatePeriod');\n" +
                "drpfromdatePeriod['0']['0']['value'] = " + date);
    }

where date is a String I'm passing the method to match the date format in my case it is mm/dd/yyyy, then I just played around with the javascript console to locate where the value can be set. So then I just update the value by accessing the 'value' attribute directly.

Comment: This can be an answer but it is not "best practice" to use `executeScript`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the Date Picker In Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422548/how-to-select-the-date-picker-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the date picker and its backing form field?

Comment: @Greg.. he's using the browser's control here.  type="datetime".  (Only works in certain browsers) Seems like you could also just use driver.sendKeys() instead of the javascript executor