# how to pick a date using select select in page object model

Tags: selenium

need to pick a date from date picker

```
WebElement  Month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div/select[2]"));
            //Select select = new Select(Month);
           // select.selectByValue("1975");
```

Not picked only current month and year picked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the Date Picker In Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422548/how-to-select-the-date-picker-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please paste html code.

Answer (score 1):

Its an **select** tag then you can use Selenium Select class itself instead of using standard script

```
Example:

    Select fruits = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));
    fruits.selectByVisibleText("Banana");  // by visible text 
    fruits.selectByIndex(1);  // by index
    fruits.selectByValue("23-10-2019");  //select by value
```

If you want to use standard way there is solution like below:

https://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html